# What would be a good method to compare the results from my model to actual measurement data?

Tags: regression-coefficients, error, measurement-error, rms

I have a complex physical model of an engine and I get certain outputs for a given set of inputs. However, these outputs are of course, not exact and deviate from the physically observed values for the same set of inputs. Basically, $y_{sim}(t) = f(X(t))$, where $X$ is the input vector, $f(.)$ represents my model and $y_{sim}$ is my simulated output.

What would be a good measure to quantify the accuracy of my model? Apart from comparing the $RMS$ error of $y_{sim}$ and $y_{meas}$ ? Also, I have several variables $y$ which can be discrete in nature.

I have read about $RMSE, \ MAE, \ MAPE, \ MASE, \ MRAE,\ R^2, $ but found some issue with each method.

Comment: Your findings are absolutely correct. None of these methods is clearly better than the other because each is focused on a different aspect of the data ($R^2$ and RMSE are commonely *very* correlated though). What you should do is decide which one is more relevant from your problem at hand. Similarly, you might choose to show two or three measurements to allow the read to have a more holistic view (personally, I commonly report RMSE and MAE in regression problem so people are not mislead than one another.)

Comment: @usεr11852 That's absolutely true. Even I am thinking of doing that. My only concern being, since both of them are unit dependent quantities, it's difficult to make sense of how good or bad a model is, just by looking at those numbers. For eg. RMSE = 100 may mean extremely different for Pressure and Temperature.

Comment: And using relative errors has a bunch of its own issues like blowing up for values close to 0 :(